# HERE autosuggest get complete address informations

Tags: javascript, here-api, here-autocomplete

I'm currently working with HERE API, using autosuggest to get my results.
In the adress object of each response I only got "label" who look like this :

```
"address": { "label": "Resort Mark Brandenburg, An der Seepromenade 20, 16816 Neuruppin, Germany" },
```

Is there a way to optain complete informations like `discover` or `autocomplete` do ?
Like having countryCode, city, street in the address object ?

On this page https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html at autosuggest menu we can see all the informations in the response samples.

I'm using this query at the moment :

```
https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?apiKey=MYAPIKEY&result_types=address,place&in=bbox:0.5833,42.9667,2.241295,44.210550&in=countryCode:FRA&q=apitol&limit=5&content-type=application/json&lang=fr-fr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this parameter "&show=details" for show address details.

Answer (score 1):

If some additional fields to be rendered in the response, then you have to pass the "show" tag in the request query string. Please note that some of the fields involve additional webservice calls and can increase the overall response time.

More details regarding "show" tag are covered in below API specs.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html

Sample Request Query.

https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY&result_types=address,place&in=bbox:0.5833,42.9667,2.241295,44.210550&in=countryCode:FRA&q=apitol&limit=5&content-type=application/json&lang=fr-fr&show=details